# How do I use the downloaded android holo icons, stencils, fonts?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget, android-holo-everywhere

I have downloaded the entire pack from `http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html` 
I want to know how to use those. Do I place it somewhere in the android sdk folder so that it is visible in my Graphical Layout in Eclipse editor or should i be using the individual icons and fonts as required  in my project by placing it in the `drawable-hdpi` folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Place them in the appropriate drawable folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using one of the latest versions of the Android Development Tools in Eclipse, you can just go to New->Other, and the Android->Android Icon Set and it will show you a step by step Wizard where you can select all those images, the color, name, sizes, and it will automatically place the different versions in the corresponding folders.

You can check it out [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/assetstudiointegration). Also, at the beggining of the linked page, there´s another link to the web app version that allows you to easily create nine-patch images, besides icons and other assets.

Comment: This is very useful procedure to configure the icons and other images. Thanks a lot. I have known that icons could be placed manually but wanted to know if all of them could be imported at once to be displayed in the graphical layout. Although that's not possible, using your procedure I could now customize before using the icons in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put them manually in the drawable-mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi folders.